# Can we see our personal stats?

Tags: feature-request, support, badges, privileges

Is it possible to view our personal stats on the site (number of x until level y or badge z)?

If so, how?

If not, is there any feature being worked on for this?

Answer (score 3):

For privileges, go to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=all.

Badges are described briefly at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=all and more fully at [http://meta.stackoverflow.‍com/q/67397](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397), but I know of no way for a user to know how close he is to all the badges.

There is info on some badges, though:

- The Reviewer badge requires one to issue 250 reviews of the same type, and the Steward badge requires 1000; you can see how many (for example) closure reviews you've issued at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats.)
- You can check your status regarding the Civic Duty, Copy Editor, Custodian, Electorate, Reviewer, and Steward badges by hovering over the percentage-done bar to the right of the "Review" header on any of the review pages ([e.g.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts)).
- You can check your status regarding the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges on SEDE [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/miyodeya/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i).
- You can check your status regarding the Pundit badge on SEDE [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/miyodeya/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution).
- You can check your status regarding the Civic Duty, Electorate, Deputy, and Marshal badges on your user page.
- You can check your status regarding the Epic and Legendary badges [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/reputation) at the bottom.
- [Stinking Badges!](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge/) is an unofficial (AFAIK not SE-supported) way to see your progress toward certain badges.

*This answer is community-wiki: it's easy for others to edit. Please add info on more badges to this list!*

Comment: There used to be a way to track progress towards Copy Editor in the review tab. I don't see it anymore because I have the badge. It might still exist.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah. Maybe I should make this answer CW and ask people to contribute what they know.

Comment: Most of it has been dealt with on MSO already

Comment: @DoubleAA, yeah, but not all in one place AFAICT.